# python 2.7 program does not insert data in the database

Tags: python, mysql, xampp

I have the following database structure in XAMPP localhost port 3306 
dbname-test,table name-student,roll varchar(100),name varchar(100)
The program given below does not insert the data from the user input. The table stays blank

```
import mysql.connector
roll=raw_input("Enter your Roll: ")
name=raw_input("Enter your Name: ")  
db=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='test' ,user='root'               
,password='000000')
s="insert into student(roll,name) values('"+roll+"','"+name+"');"
cur=db.cursor()
if[cur.execute(s)==True]:
    print ("Query Successful")
else:
    print ("Query not Successful")
cur.commit()
cur.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [commit](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit) the changes to the database before you close the connection.

```
cnx.commit()
```

So in your case you would use

```
db.commit()
```

Comment: Yeah my mistake - the connection object has the commit() method not the cursor